# Marking PHAR archive as PHP executable

Tags: php, phar

I'm trying to make my PHAR archive *marked as PHP* (*I don't know correct term for this*) so that I can use it from cli without `php` part. So instead of calling `php /path/to/my/archive.phar ARGUMENTS_HERE` I can just move it to `/usr/local/bin` and call it `archive` from anywhere. (Just like PHPUnit or Composer).

If I'm right, to do that, I just need to add `#!/usr/bin/env php` on top of my PHAR archive file?

How do I do that? I tried to mimic [composer compiler](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Compiler.php) in my **build** script, but it just **crashes PHP_CLI (segmentation fault)**:

```
$archiveName = 'phpbenchmark.phar';

$phar = new Phar($archiveName);

$phar->buildFromDirectory(__DIR__, '/\/lib\/|\/vendor\//');

$phar->setStub(createStub());

function createStub()
{
    $stub = <<<EOD
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
Phar::mapPhar('phpbenchmark.phar');
require 'phar://phpbenchmark.phar/lib/app.php';
__HALT_COMPILER();
EOD;
    return $stub;
}
```

As you can see, I only need stub to run `/lib/app.php` file and that's it.

#### Prepending to compiled PHAR

Of course, first thing I tried was manually prepending it to my archive, but it looks like that corrupts it:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'manifest cannot be larger than 100 MB in phar "/home/igor/Dropbox/www/Github/PIFlexPHPBenchmark/phpbenchmark.phar"' in /home/igor/Dropbox/www/Github/PIFlexPHPBenchmark/phpbenchmark.phar:9
Stack trace:
#0 /home/igor/Dropbox/www/Github/PIFlexPHPBenchmark/phpbenchmark.phar(9): Phar::webPhar(NULL, 'index.php')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/igor/Dropbox/www/Github/PIFlexPHPBenchmark/phpbenchmark.phar on line 9

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'manifest cannot be larger than 100 MB in phar "/home/igor/Dropbox/www/Github/PIFlexPHPBenchmark/phpbenchmark.phar"' in /home/igor/Dropbox/www/Github/PIFlexPHPBenchmark/phpbenchmark.phar on line 9

PharException: manifest cannot be larger than 100 MB in phar "/home/igor/Dropbox/www/Github/PIFlexPHPBenchmark/phpbenchmark.phar" in /home/igor/Dropbox/www/Github/PIFlexPHPBenchmark/phpbenchmark.phar on line 9

Call Stack:
    0.0010     306272   1. {main}() /home/igor/Dropbox/www/Github/PIFlexPHPBenchmark/phpbenchmark.phar:0
    0.0011     307840   2. Phar::webPhar() /home/igor/Dropbox/www/Github/PIFlexPHPBenchmark/phpbenchmark.phar:9
```

Note that **exactly the same** archive works before I manually modify it. (But needs `php /path/to/arch` of course)

Comment: Don't you just add `#!/usr/bin/env php` to the top of the file, above the opening `<?php` tag and `chmod` the file as executable?

Comment: I tried that first, but it doesn't work. I edited my question to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaand, solved (kinda) after few hours of breaking my head. I still have no idea why, this build script seems to work:

```
$archiveName = 'phpbenchmark.phar';

$phar = new Phar($archiveName);

$phar->buildFromDirectory(__DIR__, '/\/lib\/|\/vendor\//');

$phar->setStub(createStub());

function createStub()
{
    $stub = <<<ENDSTUB
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
Phar::mapPhar('phpbenchmark.phar');
require 'phar://phpbenchmark.phar/lib/app.php';
__HALT_COMPILER();
ENDSTUB;

    return $stub;
}
```

Except.....I can't really see any differences to original script posted in my question? Why would original one crash PHP Cli and this one works?

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do to get that to work is update the line:

```
$phar->setStub($phar->createDefaultStub("main.php"));
```

to :

```
$phar->setStub("#!/usr/bin/env php\n\n" . $phar->createDefaultStub("main.php"));
```

This takes the default stub that phar creates for you, and adds the requires #! line to it. Then just chmod 700 the resulting phar file, and you are good to go.